# Install Canon LBP3000 printer on 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

good afternoon,

I have a Canon LBP3000 printer and I can not install it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit,

I downloaded drivers for Canon i386 (cndrvcups-common_2.20-1_i386.deb and cndrvcups-capt_2.20-1_i386.deb) along with architecture i386 but when I try to install the drivers I appear dependencies that can not be installed

```
cndrvcups-common:i386 : Depende: libglade2-0:i386 (>= 1:2.4.2-2) pero no va a instalarse
                 Depende: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.6.0) pero no va a instalarse
                 Depende: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.6.0) pero no va a instalarse
                 Depende: libpango1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.8.1) pero no va a instalarse
                 Depende: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.6.16) pero no va a instalarse
                 Depende: gs-esp:i386 pero no es instalable
                 Depende: libcups2:i386 pero no va a instalarse o
                          libcupsys2:i386 (>= 1.1.23) pero no es instalable
libatk1.0-0:i386 :   Depende: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.41.1) pero no va a instalarse
```

any solution?

I found several solutions for 14.04 but for 16.04 found nothing,

Can I install the LBP3000 in this version of Ubuntu?

Thank you,

regards,

Comment: I suggest you try a much newer version of the driver, 2.70 perhaps, from here: http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp3000.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)

Comment: Please advise if you need specific instructions.

Comment: This is the driver that I download and try to install. 
I need to know specifically is how I can fix the error in the installation of ghostscript package and the libcupsys2 and libcup2 libraries. In Ubuntu 16.04 these libraries can not be installed